# moxtra - is there a way to create ephemeral chat session? using binder_id to join chat creates persisted chat

Tags: chat

I would like to have two people join the same chat session.  I noticed that using the binder_id to let users join the same chat, the chat data seems to be persistent. That is, the next time the users decide to chat, they will see the data from previous session. Is there a way to create ephemeral chat session that is erased when the chat session is closed or when everyone left the chat session?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. You can integrate "Meet" instead of chat. With meet the session data is not stored. The users will not see the data from previous session when you start a new meet.
2. If you don't want to integrate "meet" instead of chat, then you will have to delete the binder after every chat session. You can delete a binder by making a REST API call. Here are the details: https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-rest-api/#binder-apis

Comment: Thank you.  I see.  option #1 should be good enough.  If we go with option #2 to delete the binder after chat session, how do we tell that the session is ended.  Looking at the api, I found a end_meet callback, but I do not see a end_chat callback?

Comment: Chat will not end. It persists as it is a binder. It's the binder owner's decision to delete the binder. You can have a "End Chat" button, when clicked, you delete the binder.

Comment: I see.  chat does not end.  meeting does not end.